# Error while building cSipSimple source

Tags: android, ubuntu, csip-simple

I am trying to build the cSipSimple source for android. I think ,I am followed the steps described in [how to build wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild) of cSipSimple. But unfortunately I am facing a make error. Here is the command log info.

```
Now at patch 001toolchain_static_lib.diff
cd build/armeabi; \
 if [ "build/armeabi/config.mk" = "build/armeabi/config.mk" ]; then TGT=armv5te-android-gcc; fi; \
 if [ "build/armeabi-v7a/config.mk" = "build/armeabi/config.mk" ]; then TGT=armv7-android-gcc; fi; \
 if [ "build/x86/config.mk" = "build/armeabi/config.mk" ]; then TGT=x86-android-gcc; fi; \
 if [ "build/mips/config.mk" = "build/armeabi/config.mk" ]; then TGT=mips32-android-gcc; fi; \
 BUILD_PFX=jni/libvpx/build/armeabi/ ../../sources/configure --target=$TGT --disable-examples --sdk-path=
Not a directory: 


Configuration failed. This could reflect a misconfiguration of your
toolchains, improper options selected, or another problem. If you
don't see any useful error messages above, the next step is to look
at the configure error log file (config.err) to determine what
configure was trying to do when it died.
make[1]: *** [build/armeabi/config.mk] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/alexchengalan/android/files/CSipSimple-trunk/CSipSimple/jni/libvpx'
make: *** [jni/libvpx/sources] Error 2
```

I think the error is pointing out on `--disable-examples --sdk-path=
    Not a directory:` on the above. But I don't know what it means.

I also added following lines to the .bashrc file

```
export ANDROID_NDK=/home/alexchengalan/android/files/android-ndk-r10d/
export ANDROID_SDK=/home/alexchengalan/android/files/android-sdk-linux/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK
```

It would be nice if anyone can help me out from this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found where was my problem. I needed to add the following lines to the `.bashrc` file.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/..your sdk path.../android-sdk-linux
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```